# Elasticsearch with laravel inaccurate search

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

I integrated Elasticsearch in my Laravel application (Laravel Scout with ErickTamayo/laravel-scout-elastic driver). Everything is works well. But I have one problem. For example, when I search phrase "HOU" , it finds result which contains word "altHOUgh". It is not normal in my opinion. How I can resolve it?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the code you are using so you can be helped better.

Comment: Post::search($search_text)->take(2000)->get()